# How can I create macros which generate only part of a tabular row?

Tags: tables, macros

So, the project I'm working on a project which involves a glossary. Now, I have an idea of how I want to typeset this, but I also, in good LaTeX fashion, want to abstract away from the particulars of the layout. The glossary will have a basic two-column layout. Here's working code which generates at least the output  want:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,draft]{article}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\GlossaryEntry}[3]{#1 & #2 & #3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\toprule
\GlossaryEntry{foo}{n}{lorem ipsum dolor sit} & 
\GlossaryEntry{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit} \\
\GlossaryEntry{bar}{v}{sed do eiusmod tempor} &
\GlossaryEntry{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, this is workable, but notice that I still have to worry about which column I'm in, and insert the `&` or `\\` as appropriate. What I would like, is something like this:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,draft]{article}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newboolean{TabRowStart}
\setboolean{TabRowStart}{true}


\newcommand{\GlossaryEntry}[3]{
\ifthenelse{\boolean{TabRowStart}}
    {\setboolean{TabRowStart}{false}#1 & #2 & #3 &}
    {\setboolean{TabRowStart}{true}#1 & #2 & #3 \\}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\toprule
\GlossaryEntry{foo}{n}{lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\GlossaryEntry{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit}
\GlossaryEntry{bar}{v}{sed do eiusmod tempor}
\GlossaryEntry{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I have a boolean which is set up to check whether I'm in the first part or the second part of each row, and then acts accordingly

Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile. When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.22 ...Entry{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit}
```

My initial thought was that it has something to do with the use of `\\` in the command. However, strangely, this code works fine:

```
...
\newcommand{\GlossaryEntryDouble}[6]{%
#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 & #6 \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\toprule
\GlossaryEntryDouble{foo}{n}{lorem ipsum dolor sit}{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit} 
\GlossaryEntryDouble{bar}{v}{sed do eiusmod tempor}{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
...
```

So it doesn't look like it's the presence of `\\` in itself which is causing the issue.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to reinvent the wheel rather than using the existing circular design?

Comment: Hopefully you don't want to deviate from your input. That is, allow for insertion of multiple (two) `\GlossaryEntry`s and then occasionally just one with a forced ``\\``, because you feel like it. Right?

Comment: @cfr Well, there's a few other things I wanted to do that I didn't mention here. Also, I was just curious what I was missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean should be set globally, because cells form groups.

However, you'll be in trouble if the number of entries is odd, so an expandable test must be used.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{TabRowStart}
\toggletrue{TabRowStart}


\newcommand{\GlossaryEntry}[3]{%
  \iftoggle{TabRowStart}
    {\global\togglefalse{TabRowStart}#1 & #2 & #3 &}
    {\global\toggletrue{TabRowStart}#1 & #2 & #3 \\}%
}
\newcommand{\xbottomrule}{%
  \iftoggle{TabRowStart}{\bottomrule}{\\\bottomrule}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\toprule
\GlossaryEntry{foo}{n}{lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\GlossaryEntry{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit}
\GlossaryEntry{bar}{v}{sed do eiusmod tempor}
\GlossaryEntry{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore}
\xbottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\toprule
\GlossaryEntry{foo}{n}{lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\GlossaryEntry{qux}{adj}{consectetur adipiscing elit}
\GlossaryEntry{bar}{v}{sed do eiusmod tempor}
\GlossaryEntry{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore}
\GlossaryEntry{baz}{prep}{incididunt ut labore et dolore}
\xbottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note you have to use `\xbottomrule`, that will look whether the toggle is true or false and act on consequence.

[image]